# Ways to plot 3D variogram

Tags: 3d, kriging, covariogram

I am trying to plot 3D variogram of porosity taking X and Y as coordinates and z as time. Can someone help me out to find a way to plot 3D variogram?

I have tried with GSTools, pykridge, GStat.

Answer (score 0):

GSTools developer here. GSTools provides plotting routines for spatial variograms ([documentation example](https://geostat-framework.readthedocs.io/projects/gstools/en/stable/examples/02_cov_model/02_aniso_rotation.html#sphx-glr-examples-02-cov-model-02-aniso-rotation-py))

```py
import gstools as gs
model = gs.Gaussian(dim=3, var=2.0, len_scale=[10, 2], angles=2.5)
model.plot("vario_spatial")
```

[image: spatial_vario]

Then you could save images for each plane (xy, xz, yz).

Hope that helps! Cheers, Sebastian